# What is the kashrut status of Maldon Sea Salt Flakes?

Tags: kosher

Does anyone know about the kashrut status of Maldon Salt? I have heard that salt does not need a kosher certification, but I am not sure if this is true for finishing salts because of the extra process to turn the salts into crystal flakes.

I am aware that "kosher" has dual meaning in the context of salt. I am trying to ascertain the status of Maldon Salt flakes with regard to Jewish ritual law, not it's classification as a type of coarse salt that may be used to remove blood from meat (i.e. Kosher[ing] Salt).

Bonus question: what is the kashrut status Maldon's Smoky Sea Salt Flakes?

Comment: https://www.koshertoday.com/news/maldon-salt-company-receives-kosher-certification

Answer (score 2):

Welcome!
As @Max wrote, Maldon sea salt flakes are kosher!
https://www.koshertoday.com/news/maldon-salt-company-receives-kosher-certification

However, no mention was made of smoky sea salt flakes, so I would add the "smoky" with a different kosher product, depending on your taste.